# Not able to access some websites

Tags: dns, website

I am not able to access some websites . A friend of mine told me to change the DNS . I checked the Network Connections in the Network and Sharing center . Both IPV4 and IPV6 are completely empty . What to do now ? The websites are accessible via proxy.

Answer (score 1):

1). **if you have a router** - try changing DNS there (enter router address in any browser (usually 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1) then enter login name and password). I suggest you to try free google DNS:
8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

2). **if you don't have a router.** Go to "network and sharing". Choose your connection -> properties -> IPv4 settings -> properties. Choose "Use following DNS addresses" and enter google DNS suggested above.

3). **if you have programs such as PeerBlock** - disable it. These programs block HTTP traffic.

4). go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

and make sure that the website that you are trying to access isn't in "hosts" file

Comment: I don't know the device I have is a router or not . It looks like this but a different model http://www.gcci.net/images/ruckus-pr.jpg . The default ip address on the device is 192.168.30.1 . Tried it but doesn't work . Tried your given addresses . They don't work either . All columns/rows in IPV4 and IPV6 are empty . No , I don't have any program like PeerBlock installed

Comment: @Niks: It has "router" written on it.

Comment: nope ... but on the back its written " 2211 Metro Broadband Gateway" . Ruckus MM2211 is the company name + model no.  of the device.

Comment: try this address "192.168.2.1". and if it's not working - try to connect to the internet bypassing the router and see if it makes any difference! You may want to write down your IP address, mask, etc. in case if your IP is static (in this case you will need to configure your connection manually). if it's dynamic - you don't have to know the IP. so, try to connect the internet cable to PC directly.

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: If your IP is static (it doesn't change with time) - all information about the connection should be in your ISP agreement/contract. Either that, or you can call them and ask how to configure internet connection manually. Now, if you meant to ask about "bypassing the router" part - it's simple. Just unplug the internet cable that connects to your router and plug it into your Laptop's Ethernet socket. Although I'd suggest you to **call the ISP service first and ask if the DNS that they've provided have any troubles with the websites that you are trying to visit..**